# Function to create buffers of different sizes in Google Earth Engine

Tags: buffer, google-earth-engine

I want to generate a function that allows me to generate buffers of different sizes for the same `FeatureCollection`. Consider the example below. Instead of repeating the code for buffers of size 100 and 200, I want to create a function that uses as input the sizes of the buffers.

```js
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection('xxxxx');

var bufferPoly100 = function(feature) {
  return feature.buffer(100);   
};

var bufferPoly200 = function(feature) {
  return feature.buffer(200);   
};

var bufferedPolys100 = polygons.map(bufferPoly100);
var bufferedPolys200 = polygons.map(bufferPoly200);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're only looking to reduce the code duplication in your script so far, not to change the number away from a "hardcoded" one, then you can use a function returning a function:

```js
var bufferBy = function(size) {
  return function(feature) {
    return feature.buffer(size);   
  };
};

var bufferedPolys100 = polygons.map(bufferBy(100));
var bufferedPolys200 = polygons.map(bufferBy(200));
```

Answer (score 5):

The following function `BufferFeaturesByDistance` takes a buffer size as an input. The "trick" to implementing this is to store the input parameter (buffer_size) as a feature property, which can be used when mapping a function across a FeatureCollection.

```js
// Setup some test data.
var polys = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(1, 55, 2, 55.3)),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(3, 55, 4, 55.3)),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.LineString([[1.5, 54.5],
                                       [2.0, 54.0],
                                       [3.1, 54.0],
                                       [3.6, 54.5]]))
]);

// Create a function for Buffering a feature, using the buffer_size
// property of the feature.
var BufferFeature = function(f) {
  f = ee.Feature(f);
  var buffer_size = f.get('buffer_size');
  return f.buffer(buffer_size);   
};

var BufferFeaturesByDistance = function (fc, buffer_size) {

  // Set a buffer_size property on a feature. Note that this function needs
  // to be defined within the BufferFeaturesByDistance function, so it can
  // make use of the buffer_size parameter.
  var SetBufferSize = function(f) {
    return f.set({'buffer_size': buffer_size});
  };

  return polys.map(SetBufferSize).map(BufferFeature);
};

var buffered1 = BufferFeaturesByDistance(polys, 10000);
var buffered2 = BufferFeaturesByDistance(polys, 20000);

Map.addLayer(polys, {}, 'polys');
Map.addLayer(buffered1, {color:'red'}, 'buffered1');
Map.addLayer(buffered2, {color:'green'}, 'buffered2');
```

The resulting buffered geometries look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the script results]

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I'm not sure how your answer differs from Kevin Reid's answer and his code is simpler. Is there an advantage of your method I'm not seeing?

Comment: Yes, Kevin does have a simpler solution. Storing function parameters as feature properties can be useful for more complex use cases (such as buffers that vary by feature), but here it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you want to set the size of the buffers based on a property of each feature.

In this example, we have point data with a property that gives the area of the associated mineral rights in hectares. We will buffer each point so that the resulting (circular) buffer is the same area.

```
    //define a variable buffer based on a property
var buffered = YourInputFeatureCollection.map(function(feature){
  
  //you need an expression to do math, and if you want to use a variable in an expression you have to wrap it in a dictionary
  var area = ee.Dictionary({value:feature.get('YourPropertyName')})
  
  //define the buffer as a new geometry
  var buffered_point = feature.geometry().buffer(
    ee.Number.expression('sqrt((value*10000)/Math.PI)',area) //starting units are ha (=10,000 square meters)
    )
  
  //coerce that geometry to a feature, copy the properties of the input feature, and return it
  return(ee.Feature(buffered_point).copyProperties(feature))
})

print(buffered)
```